# Does the way we see the world in vision change with age?

Tags: perception, vision

I clearly remember a period in my youth where the world looked better, more colorful.

Cartoons and videogames, drawings and pictures seemed higher resolution.

Around the age of 15 I started noticing more details about the same things I was used to always see...

Some things I have seen for almost an entire decade at this point, so it is improbable that I was simply distracted, and I can clearly remember how things looked like to the smallest details...now they look different.

I have no idea how to research this, what do I google? What am I even supposed to search?

I only have two hypothesis, maybe my vision got better with age and now I can see the details or actually lack of details in cartoons and various pictures and I can notice the ugly details of the world, maybe this distracts me from the colours making everything look less intense.

I know for a fact that my vision did not get worse as my left eye is now 10/10 like always and my right eye went from 2/10 to 4.5/10. But this is a lazy eye condition and my brain never uses my right eye unless I close my left one. Basically I have always had monocular vision because the right side of my view is just fog therefore my brain ignores it and removes it from my vision. Even if I focused and really wanted it, I can't see with both eyes at once.

My other idea is that maybe as a child everything new just seemed more wonderful to me and my mind just imagined all that extra colour.

Are there any sources regarding this situation?

Comment: I also know that I’m not the only one because I know other people who experienced the same exact thing, probably it's hard to explain it to people who never experienced it ..probably like teaching colours to a blind person.

Comment: Welcome to Psychology.SE. Just a word of warning that where you included personal medical details concerning your eye sight etc. it could be seen that your question could be seeking personal advice which is off-topic here. I know this information is in there for personal evaluation purposes only so I would say it is fine in this instance. Just a friendly guide for future questions you may ask

Comment: As for a possible answer, maybe it is just that we become more critical of the world around us as we get older. I know I have. There were cases of [rosy retrospection](https://psychology.wikia.org/wiki/Rosy_retrospection) but breaking down biases can lead to more questioning and criticism in life I suppose.

Comment: Welcome to psych.SE.  I'm afraid this question has a couple of issues currently: It is clearly a self-help question as-is, and it is phrased as a medical rather than psychology question.  I am going to close it for now, but if you would like to edit the question to remove the self-help aspect, and focus on the perception elements, rather than medical ones (eg: "How does color vision deteriorate with age?" or "Does the qualia of colour change with age?") then you can nominate it for reopening.